# データフレームの1変数を、分割し、別の変数として保存するには？

Tags: python, pandas

今、下記の表のように、ｘとyの変数からなるデータフレーム(data)があります。
変数xが"/"で区切られておりますが、これらを別の4つの変数、例えば
A, B, C,Dに分割したいと考えています。

index   　x  　　y
1   　52/26/3/8  　　34
2   　52/26/9/10 　28
3   　110/55/4/9 　50

dataから xを取り出し、splitにより分割したいのですが、
うまく行かず困っています。適当な方法をご教示願いたいのですが。

Comment: どこがうまく行かないのですか？

Comment: 具体的なコード片があると、データをどのように管理しようとして、どう上手くいっていないのかが理解しやすいと思いますので、追記願えませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えば下記のような動作では如何でしょうか。期待した結果でない場合は申し訳ありません。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['52/26/3/8', '52/26/9/10', '110/55/4/9'],
     'y': [34, 28, 50]},
    index=[1, 2, 3])

splitted = df['x'].str.split('/', expand=True)
splitted.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

print(df)
            x   y
1   52/26/3/8  34
2  52/26/9/10  28
3  110/55/4/9  50

print(splitted)
     A   B  C   D
1   52  26  3   8
2   52  26  9  10
3  110  55  4   9
```

Answer (score 0):

早速のお返事を、ありがとうございます。
下記のコードでうまく動きました。

splitted = df['x'].str.split('/', expand=True)
splitted.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Comment: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧の上、回答の承認などをお願いします。意図せずアカウントが分かれてしまった場合は[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をご覧下さい。